# Spring+Thymeleaf: post data from modal form

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to post data from html form into database. I have gradle project with springboot and thymeleaf. 
I have java object Class witch has id, name, description, teacher and minutes.
In html I use modal form to ask for all but id.

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <title>Class Scheduler</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Class Scheduler</h2>
        <div class="text-right"> 
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addClassModal">Add new class</button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="addClassModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addClassModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addClassModalLabel">Add new class</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form th:action="@{/addClass}" th:object="${class}" method="post">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" th:value="*{name}"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="description">Description:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" th:value="*{description}"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="teacher">Teacher:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="teacher" th:value="*{teacherName}"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="minutes">Minutes:</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="minutes" th:value="*{timeMinutes}"/>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class ScheduleController {

    @Autowired
    private ClassService classService;
    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/addClass", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addClass(@RequestAttribute("class") Class newClass, Model model) {
        classService.addClass(newClass);
        return "main";
    }
```

The error message, that I get is: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'class' available as request attribute.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
My ClassService looks like this:

```
@Service
public class ClassService{

    private static final BeanPropertyRowMapper<Class> CLASS_ROW_MAPPER = BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance( Class.class );

    @Autowired
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;


    public void addClass(final Class newClass) {
        MapSqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        in.addValue("id", newClass.getId());
        in.addValue("name", newClass.getName());
        in.addValue("description", newClass.getDescription());
        in.addValue("teacher_name", newClass.getTeacherName());
        in.addValue("time_minutes", newClass.getTimeMinutes());
        namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO class(name, description, teacher_name, time_minutes) values(:name,:description,:teacher_name,:time_minutes)", in);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your ClassService class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
 public String addClass(@RequestAttribute("class") Class newClass, Model model) {
```

Use ModelAttribute instead of RequestAttribute

```
 public String addClass( @ModelAttribute("class") Class newClass, Model model) {
```

Also, in your controller class return an instance of Class associated with the ModelAttribute

```
@ModelAttribute(value = "class")
public Class getClass()
{
    return new Class();
}
```

Comment: @Jack69: Updated my answer , check now